# Calculate the amount money using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count how much user ID 1 has money on their account. I don't have a column with the amount of money because I want to keep simple Double-entry bookkeeping.

So I would like to calculate it based on the transactions made on the SQL operation in my PostgreSQL database. My table looks similar to this:

```
  id  sender_id    recipient_id           amount_money
  --- -----------  ---------------------- -----------------
  1   1            2                      60.00
  2   1            2                      15.00
  3   2            1                      35.00
```

If the user is a sender, the amount should be subtracted.
Else if the user is a recipient, the amount should be added.

So based on the available table, user id 1 should have: -40.00 and user id 2 should have: 40.00.

How can I do this on PostgreSQL, providing only the user's id number in the argument? I can't program in SQL so well that I can handle it myself.

btw, is it okay to do this with SQL? My application backend is written in NodeJS. I did a small analysis and decided that my way of saving money would be fine, but I'm just a programmer with one year's experience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[On demand count inventory scan efficiently in SQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/54243544/90527)", "[SQL conditional addition or subtraction](//stackoverflow.com/q/1429769/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when recipient_id = 2 then 1 else -1 end * amount_money) total
from tablename
where 2 in (sender_id, recipient_id)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/veTZUDAtNLg1zTma2sCBM5/0).
Results:

```
| total |
| ----- |
| 40.00 |
```